# Subtract column of integers from Date column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to subtract a column of integers from a Date format column in T-SQL within a case statement however there's get a conversion error. I understand the reason for the error but not how to resolve it.

```sql
CASE 
    WHEN EVT = 'x' 
        THEN DATEADD(DAY, -[DATE COLUMN], [INTEGER COLUMN]) 
        ELSE [DATE COLUMN 2] - [INTEGER COLUMN] 
END AS y
```

Have tried it with and without the square brackets.

Any suggestions please?

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. If there is an error then provide the complete error message and when it occurs. A complete example with sample data helps us help you.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consult the [official MS Documentation on `DATEADD`, you'll see the proper syntax:

```
DATEADD (datepart, number, date)
```

So I would guess in your case, it should be:

```
CASE 
    WHEN EVT = 'x' 
        THEN DATEADD(DAY, -1 * [INTEGER COLUMN], [DATE COLUMN]) 
        ELSE DATEADD(DAY, -1 * [INTEGER COLUMN], [DATE COLUMN 2])
END AS y
```

assuming you want to subtract the value of the integer column as days from either of the two date columns.

Answer (score 1):

If both columns are datetime columns - and you want to subtract days:

```
iif(EVT = 'x', [DATE COLUMN], [DATE COLUMN2]) - [INTEGER COLUMN]
```

As a CASE expression (which IIF will be converted to):

```
CASE WHEN EVT = 'x' THEN [DATE COLUMN] ELSE [DATE COLUMN2] END - [INTEGER COLUMN]
```

If your date columns are date, datetime2, datetimeoffset data types - then you must use DATEADD:

```
DATEADD(day, -[INTEGER COLUMN], IIF(EVT = 'x', [DATE COLUMN], [DATE COLUMN2]))
```

Comment: You should **not** use `[date] - [integer]` - what exactly does that mean?? Date minus years? Months? Days? Hours? You should be **specific and clear** about your intent - therefore always use `DATEADD()`. The "abbreviated"  "date - int" syntax is *no longer valid* with the newer SQL Server 2008+ date datatypes anyway - `DATETIME2`, `DATE`, `DATETIMEOFFSET` throw an error, if you try this "shortcut"